# Detecting Yes and No on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my `handleLongHeld:`,

I have the following line

```
  if(Users_pressed_ok) // How do I do this?
```

I can detect when okay is pressed and as you can see the second method logs it to the log and I can see that working. However, I cant think of a clean way to do the above if statement.

The only way I can think to do it, is using a global variable that gets updated for this alert.

```
-  (void)handleLongHold:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"Long press detected.");

        NSLog(@"long press ");
        UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
        UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"cancel.png"];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                              message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        [alert show];
        if(Users_pressed_ok) // How do I do this?
        [myImage removeFromSuperview];
    }

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"user pressed OK");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"user pressed Cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can move line `[myImage removeFromSuperview];` into the **if** statement(buttonIndex == 0 do this) at **clickedButtonAtIndex**

Comment: You can declare the global variable for UIImageView *myImage and then access it in the delegate method of the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert view delegate gets fired after you release the button. Try this

```
-  (void)handleLongHold:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"Long press detected.");

        NSLog(@"long press ");
        UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
        UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"cancel.png"];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                              message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"user pressed OK");
        [myImage removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"user pressed Cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure @rajesh?  because I could remember that 0 was the cancel button (a synonym for NO in objective-c too)

Comment: Do it with trial and error. I just mentioned the way of doing.

Comment: Ideally button idex 0 for cancel button

Comment: you've provided the code my friend. you had the correct answer in my opinion and it's a shame if it was bogus. if you don't mind the code could have been as simple as `if(!buttonIndex) { /*user pressed yes */}`

Comment: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);
} its 1 if you execute this

Answer (score 1):

Use `alertView.cancelButtonIndex` to check for cancel button and ivar.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using 3rd party libs you could use one of the block implementations of UIAlertView. e.g.  https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks

Then you could do something like this in you else block:

```
RIButtonItem *cancelItem = [RIButtonItem itemWithLabel:@"Cancel" action:nil];

RIButtonItem *okItem = [RIButtonItem itemWithLabel:@"OK" action:^{

  [myImage removeFromSuperview];

}];


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                          message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                          cancelButtonItem:cancelItem
                          otherButtonItems:okItem, nil];
[alert show];
```

I normally add this lib using cocoapods but you could add as a git submodule too.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the essence of the question... the `UIAlertViewDelegate` method `-alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` will communicate to you which button was pressed.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch(buttonIndex) {
        case 0: //first button was selected
            break;
        case 1: //second button was selected
            break;
        //...
        case N: //Nth button was selected
            break;
    }
}
```

FYI: `buttonIndex` 0 will be whichever button was specified first.

So...

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                message:nil
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
//Cancel is 0
```

---

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                message:nil
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
//Ok is 0
```

---

```
UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                 message:nil
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
//Ok is 0
```

*PS: Whatever be it, it doesn't matter. Only your logic matters (and code conformity)*